# rotate ellipse with one finger (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Using WPF I need to (touch) rotate ellipse with one finger only (one manipulator) ?

Like old phones radial dial

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: appreciated if you could flash some sample code as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite easy to do. All you need is to recall your high school geometry classes :)

1. Handle `ManipulationStarted` event, save your starting point in the event handler. Let's call the point `S` (start).
2. Let `O` be the center of your ellipse. Find vector `a = OS`.
3. In the `ManipulationDelta` handler get your the finger's location. Let's call it `M`.
4. Find vector `b = OM`.
5. Now you can use a simple formula: `var angle = Math.Abs(Math.Atan2(a.X, a.Y) - Math.Atan2(b.X, b.Y));`

**ipi's** answer is good too, but the angle is limited by the `cos^-1` function (it won't matter if you have a solid color ellipse, otherwise your object will "teleport" after reaching `pi/2`).

Comment: Ah, I didn't there was an alternative with `Atan2`! Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the position of the center of the ellipse and you know the position of the finger, you can calculate the vector from the ellipse to the finger with `(finger vector) - (ellipse vector)`.

Then, when the finger position updates, do the above again and store it separately. Then perform the dot product on the two vectors: `A . B = |A| |B| cos(theta)`.

If A and B are unit vectors (i.e. of magnitude 1), the dot product (`(A.x * B.x) + (A.y * B.y)`) will yield `cos(theta)`. Perform the inverse operation and you will have your angle in radians. You can then perform your rotation.

More resources which elaborate on the dot product and vector maths are a Google search away...